Net force on a pressurized container car
Consider a simple case of a car in the shape of a truncated cone (the weight of which can be neglected). Assume the gas inside is ideal. The area is $2A$ on the right and $A$ on the left. The pressure inside is $P$.
Do you think that this idealized car will start moving towards right (because the force on the right face will be $2PA$ and on the left will be $PA$, resulting in a net rightward force of $PA$)? If so, what is the need for the fuel to run this car as the gas pressure is self-sufficient?
I know that the pressure inside it will reduce with time, which will cause the driver to increase the pressure (by whatever means). But is there any other reason why this idealized car is not possible?


Are the circular areas open or closed? if they are closed, all you have created is a pressurized container which will not move since the walls act on the gas with a force directly balancing out the force exerted by the pressure (this is Newton's third law). Also, you seem to have left and right mixed up.

Voting to reopen. A perfectly clear question with  a good answer below.

Leaving closed because it isn't clear and answers don't make questions on topic.

No, the car will not start to move. You are considering only the forces on the ends of the cone but neglecting the force on the side of the cone. When you include that, there is no net force left or right.
